# print mysql result with ruby mysql2

Tags: mysql, ruby

I'm using mysql2 and here is my code:

mycon = Mysql2::Client.new( :host .. )

result = mycon.query(" ... ")

When I run the query via mysql program

```js
sta    info1    info2    info3

1      55        23        242
2      44        322      3223
3      33        33        31
4      22        323       31
3      11        233      323
1      32        32        323
```

How I can print all the lines that have sta=1 and sta=3 with Ruby ?

Also how I can use/take out all numbers from info2 without sta=1,3 , 
I want to query these numbers on other DB, so I think script is must.

Thanks!

Comment: I'd strongly recommend using an ORM, rather than the driver. You'll find it much easier to write your queries, and the queries you write will be more easily transferred to other DBMs if necessary. [Sequel](http://sequel.jeremyevans.net) is my favorite, but Active Record, which comes with Rails, and [DataMapper](http://datamapper.org) are also available. Otherwise, you need to read the documentation plus follow some tutorials as this is very basic use of a DB. "[ask]" plus the linked pages and http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/128421 are important reads.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use SQL to filter by the sta column:

```
SELECT sta, info1, info2, info3 from MyTable WHERE sta = 1 OR sta = 3;
```

Comment: thank you, do you know maybe how I can take out all the numbers from info2 without  sta 1,3 , I want to query these number on different db with ruby script, or maybe you can think on other solution for this ?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure what you mean. The best way to ask a question like this is to provide the input and the expected output. As far as "querying on a different db with ruby script", I'm not sure what you mean by that. For simple conditions, it's best to execute SQL within the DBMS (MySQL in your case) either via an ORM or a raw query like you're currently doing. As noted in the comment above, you'll probably need to read the documentation for whatever frameworks you're using in order to put this all together.